# Form submit callback on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I want to fire a callback **after** a form submit, which is submitting to a `iframe`. Here is my code

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe"></iframe>

<form action="http://www.otherwebsite.com/" method="GET" target="dummyframe">
    <input' type="submit"/>
    <input name="foo" value="foo"/>
    <input name="bar" value="bar"/>
</form>
```

If I understand correctly, `submit` has no callbacks. How can I fire a callback **after** the submit?

Comment: You cannot access the result on an iframe that contains another origin than the parent page. The other origin cannot run a script in the parent window either.